# AngularJs, UI-Router, ControllerAs & this, service/factory; Why it doesn`t work ? Where is mistake?

Tags: angularjs, service, angular-ui-router

I am trying to use a service with a controller and UI-Router. I understand how to use it without UI-Router, and I have found a variant how to make it work with UI-Router and done it, but it doesn't work. The browser throws a mistake and I can not find where it is in my code. Maybe there is another way to use a service in ui-router, but I find this most understandable for me. Thanks!

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
  </head>
  <body ng-app="mainApp">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**try.html**

```
<h4>{{try.articles.thereAre[1].title}}</h4>
```

And angularJS App with ui-router in two files: app.js and controller.js.
app.js

```
angular.module('mainApp', ['dndLists', 'ui.router'])
  .config(function($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider
      .state('try', {
        url: '/try',
        templateUrl: ' templates/try.html',
        controller: 'tryCtrl as try'
      })
    })
```

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('mainApp')
.service('defaultArticles', function() {
var me = this;

me.thereAre = [
  {
    id: '1',
    title: 'All Victims Are Out of the Hospit',
    titleCopy: 'All Victims Are Out of the Hospit',
    idea: "'We really were very lucky', Gov. Andrew M. Cuomo said after a significant blast in the Chelsea neighborhood of Manhattan. Nobody was killed, and all 29 of the injured have been released from the hospital. Remnants of the bomb and a second device were being investigated, and an additional 1,000 police officers and National Guard members were being deployed in the city.",
    hide_or_no: true,
    isCollapsed: true,
    picture: 'src/img/1.jpg'

  },
  {
    id: '2',
    title: 'How I Spent My New York Fashion Week',
    titleCopy: 'How I Spent My New York Fashion Week',
    idea: 'In early September, summer turns to fall and fashion turns to New York Fashion Week, the first leg in the monthlong international relay in which next spring’s collections (or sometimes this fall’s collections) are shown. New York’s week is particularly crammed, and while I raced uptown and down, subsisting on what I could cadge from catered shows and parties — a blini-and-caviar here (Ralph Lauren), a frosted mini doughnut there (Gucci), a cherry Coke Slurpee sucked down after dark (Alexander Wang) — I filled the margins of my notebook with the obscure, unexpected and pleasantly surprising. Here are some of the most memorable things I saw.',
    hide_or_no: true,
    isCollapsed: true,
    picture: 'src/img/2.jpg'
  }
 ];
})

.controller('tryCtrl', function(defaultArticles) {
var me = this;

me.artickles = defaultArticles;
})
```

I get this [mistake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ci25.png), what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template expects

```
<h4>{{try.articles.thereAre[1].title}}</h4>
```

while your code uses

```
me.artickles = defaultArticles;
```

Simply "artic**k**les" is not "articles"

*Side note: I would avoid JS keywords as `try` in any context... just a note*